# jQuery Layout Manager

Tags: jquery, layout-manager

Has anyone had any experience with a jQuery-based layout manager?  I know of only one ([JX](http://jx.myofiz.com/)) but it's somewhat bloated for my needs. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thought these links may help...

- [jQuery UI.Layout Plug-in](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)
- [6 Flexible jQuery Plugins To Control Webpage Layouts Easily](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/6-flexible-jquery-plugins-to-control-webpage-layouts-easily/)
- [11 Best jQuery Layout Plugins](http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/11-best-jquery-layout-plugins/)

Comment: jQuery UI.Layout Plug-In has proven itself stable and easy to use.  Highly recommend.

Comment: I loved the jQuery UI Layout plugin, but it appears to have been abandoned almost two years ago. Probably one of the best layout managers I've used. Hopefully the authors will open it up on github if they're giving up on it...

Comment: The last two links are dead.

Answer (score 5):

I have used the [Docking Layout Manager](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/layoutmanager) plugin with good success. Its pretty simple and fairly small, about 7 kb uncompressed.

Comment: Thank Egil. Looks nice and simple.

Comment: The Project Page under the link does no longer exist.

Comment: It appears to have moved here now:
http://www.rajeeshcv.com/page/details/6/layoutmanager-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 2):

The **Magic jQuery** plugin at : http://www.jquery-css.com/magic-jquery is a **31kb compressed web Layout manager** and much more : 

- **fixed position** 

- **Layout manager :** align and limit elements position/movement between themeselves or with the screen

 ex : http://www.jquery-css.com/web-layout-example.php

- very simple & generic **menu** stuff (which enable carrousels, tabs megadropdown menu etc in 2 sec) 

- **inner-page messages** 

- **highlight elements** (popIn / popOut in front of a dark veil)

all the best bastien

Answer (score 1):

Personally...I'd say stay away from jQuery for page layout management. You're far better off learning proper CSS layout or adopting a CSS layout framework like [Blueprint](http://code.google.com/p/blueprintcss/).

If you depend on jQuery (javascript) for page layout, there's a greater chance that your page is NOT going to fail gracefully. You also run the risk of users having Javascript disabled (in which case, even in a modern browser your page is going to fail).

Comment: Thanks Justin.  It's a good point but this particular product is being created in an intranet environment with little or no variation in browser capabilities.  But your point is well-taken.

Comment: Here is an example of what I want to do for example: http://itstar.co.uk/version2/ - how do you suggest I do this with just CSS+Blueprint? -- Blueprint set a max width for the page at 950px which is fine for a blog, but complete unacceptable in many use cases where you want to use 100% of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this will seem to be overkill for most scenarios, but for one very complex application I implemented the YUI Layout manager because it plays nice with YUI's fantastic and powerful DataTable component. It did, however, add a considerable amount of filesize overhead to the app.

I have also used the 960 CSS grid system to meet certain layout needs and can highly recommend it! http://960.gs/