# Recommendations for jQuery layout?

Tags: jquery, layout

I'd like to have a "dashboard" page of multiple, resizable, collapsible windows arranged in columns, with an easy means of persisting and resetting positions and states.  Is there a jQuery library that supports that?  Right now I'm manually setting jQuery UI dialogs, but persisting will be a pain, collapsing will be a pain, and I'm thinking someone else must have thought of this, but my search terms are a bit generic and I'm getting too much information to filter through.  I'm hoping some experienced developers have run across specific technologies I can research.

Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997314/jquery-layout-manager

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I'm looking for... that's too much information, all generalities.  I'm looking for something that will support my basic requirements without having to do do an in-depth analysis of every layout framework out there.

Comment: Perhaps jQuery Masonry is what you looking for http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: yeah I didn't see a good way to persist or collapse things with that one... it was one of the first I started researching.  But thanks!